# Reloading local module isn't working

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, python-importlib

Firstly, I know this has been posted on before, but either A) the recommendations don't work or B) the recommendation is to manually delete the module from the namespace and re-import it like normal.

I have the following module structure

```
basedir/
    pytools/
        __init__.py
        tools.py
    setup.py
    test.py
```

If I'm in the `basedir`, and import `pytools` and create an object of class `testcls`. The actual properties of the class are found in `tools.py`. `testcls` has a method called `testfunc` which simply prints out `AAA` right now:

```
>>> import pytools
>>> test = pytools.testcls()
>>> test.testfunc()
AAA
```

Let's say I change `testfunc()` to now print out `BBB`. I do so, and save the file. Then I reload the module and try again, it doesn't print out `BBB`:

```
>>> from importlib import reload
>>> reload(pytools)
>>> test = pytools.testcls()
>>> test.testfunc()
AAA
```

**However** if I do the exact same process but instead change `test.py`, import that file as a module, edit a function inside of it, and reload it, it behaves as expected:

```
>>> import test
>>> testvariable = test.testcls()
>>> testvariable.testfunc2()
AAA
# Change the function here
>>> from importlib import reload
>>> reload(test)
>>> testvariable = test.testcls()
>>> testvariable.testfunc2()
BBB
```

I really don't understand what's going on and it's just really annoying me at this point. It's also costing me a good bit of time as well, but I'm more annoyed at the moment.

Any ideas what's going on??

### Versions:

Python: 3.6.5

Interpreter: IPython, 6.2.1

Comment: hmm I'm not sure I can help, but when you reload, is the `test` variable (`test = pytools.testcls()`) still in the namespace? In that case, this might affect the reload. Maybe try deleting `test` and then reloading? Sorry if it ends up not helping - I'm writing from instinct more than experience.

Comment: What are the contents of `__init__.py`?

Comment: You must have something in the `__init__.py` because otherwise you'd be getting an `AttributeError: module 'pytools' has no attribute 'testcls'`, so please [edit] your question and show its contents, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's name things more generally:

```
basedir/
    testpackage/
        __init__.py
        testmodule.py
    test.py
```

If testmodule.py contains:

```
class TestClass:
    def test_method(self):
        print("AAA")
```

Then the following works as you expect:

```
>>> from testpackage import testmodule
>>> obj = testmodule.TestClass()
>>> obj.test_method()
DDD
>>> # === Edit ===
>>> from importlib import reload
>>> reload(testmodule)
>>> obj = testmodule.TestClass()
>>> obj.test_method()
EEE
```

But, if `__init__.py` has something like:

```
from .testmodule import TestClass
```

And you try to import (and reload) ***the package*** and not the module, the following happens:

```
>>> import testpackage
>>> obj = testpackage.TestClass()
>>> obj.test_method()
EEE
>>> # === Edit ===
>>> from importlib import reload
>>> reload(testpackage)
>>> obj = testpackage.TestClass()
>>> obj.test_method()
EEE
```

(It's unchanged)

Note the following section [of the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload):

> If a module imports objects from another module using from … import …, calling reload() for the other module does not redefine the objects imported from it — one way around this is to re-execute the from statement, another is to use import and qualified names (module.name) instead.

If you were to reload *both* the module and the package, in that order, it'd again work as you expect:

```
>>> import testpackage
>>> obj = testpackage.TestClass()
>>> obj.test_method()
HHH
>>> # === Edit ===
>>> from importlib import reload
>>> reload(testpackage.testmodule)
>>> reload(testpackage)
>>> obj = testpackage.TestClass()
>>> obj.test_method()
III
```

But this seems silly and error-prone, just use the approach in the first example:

```
from testpackage import testmodule
...
reload(testmodule)
...
```